# Set of texts of increasing difficulty

Tags: resource-request, text-corpus

I am looking for resources to progress in Latin reading.
In particular, I would like a set of texts (for example short stories or fables) whose difficulty increases as you go along.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A very good option would be *A Little Latin Reader* by Mary C. English and Georgia Irby-Massie.

The [Bryn Mawr Classical Review](https://bmcr.brynmawr.edu/2012/2012.09.11/) had the following to say about it:

> In 50 short chapters, English and Irby have assembled over 200
> passages (2-10 lines in length) of authentic Latin arranged in order
> of increasing difficulty of the grammatical or syntactical concept
> being emphasized. In Chapters 1-46, passages are drawn from Caesar,
> Catullus, Cicero, Horace, Livy, Martial, Ovid, Tacitus, and Vergil and
> from Latin inscriptions that treat aspects of daily life in the Roman
> world.

Comment: Do you know if this has a digital version available? I've found paperback editions available from various places, but didn't find a digital version for Google Books or Amazon Kindle.

Comment: @Adam No, I'm afraid I don't know anything about a digital version of it.