# Recommend a graded reading list of Latin works starting with De Bello Gallico

Tags: classical-latin

I'm about halfway through Caesar's De Bello Gallico which is typically considered the easiest work of Classical Latin for beginners. It would be good to know where to go next once I'm finished: whether De Bello Civili would be appropriate or something from a completely different author. Would be nice if the list were at the level of works rather than just authors. Poetry, prose, and theatre all welcome, but I'd like to keep the list to say, works predating 500 AD. Granted that after a certain point perceived difficulty is subjective but it would be nice to have a broader view of what I might expect to be able to read and when. Reasons for difficulty or lack thereof would also be appreciated.

My goal is to maintain an even level of difficulty, where the text is challenging me but not such that I'm forced to stop at every sentence to parse the grammar or look up new words - I'd like to be enjoying the reading experience.

Comment: This is *not* an answer (but possibly a useful a pointer) because I cannot argue the pros and cons, as my memory is hazy more than forty years after taking five years of Latin classes. If I recall correctly we followed up *De Bello Gallico*, with Sallust's *De Catilinae coniuratione*, which is also a work of high cultural significance. As I recall the degree of difficulty was noticeably higher compared to Caesar.

Comment: [Related 1](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/14964/set-of-texts-of-increasing-difficulty) and [related 2](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/20616/ranking-the-difficulty-of-latin-authors).